# "If you know" vs "If you knew"

Tags: grammar, tense, subjunctives

> It would be great if you know them both

vs

> It would be great if you knew them both

How do these sentences differ from each other?

Comment: I think one is present and another is  past tense

Comment: @JohnJoe It's possible that the second has a clause in the simple past tense, but the phrasing is more idiomatic of JavaLatte's answer below about the subjunctive.

Answer (score 3):

When talking about [hypothetical situations](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/), we use the subjunctive **were** for the verb **be** and a backshifted tense for all other verbs.

> It will be great if you know them both - *real*
>   It would be great if you knew them both - *hypothetical*

Note that there are two verbs- one in the **if** clause, the other in the main clause. Both verbs must be treated the same- both backshifted, or both not backshifted.

The second of your sentences is clearly hypothetical- both verbs are backshifted (will->would, know->knew). The first sentence is grammatically incorrect: the first verb is backshifted, but the second is not. You might hear somebody saying this in everyday conversation, but you should not write like this.